# can a scheduled task run a c# console app or a java command?

Tags: java, scheduled-task

I have 2 tasks that need to be run, 1 of them is a c# console application and another is a java application (main/console app also).

Can a scheduled task make a call to the cmd prompt like:

java -jar blah.jar

Answer (score 1):

Sure can running a C# console apps or java JAR files should be straight forward. I've found it easier to create a batch file for running a JAVA app only because it was easier to change things later For e.g. add libraries to a classpath or change the VM heap size etc.